# Best way to set state using dynamic key name?

Tags: reactjs

I have a state that is as follows:

```
state = {
    isDirty: false,
    form: {
        username: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
    }
}
```

I have a couple of input fields that are linked back to the state via the `onChanged` event that call using a matching ID and using the function below:

```
inputChangedHandler = (event) => {
    const updatedState = { ...this.state, isDirty: true };

    updatedState.form[event.target.id] = event.target.value;

    this.setState(updatedState);
}
```

My question is this the best way to set the state when the form is being bound?  Is there a way to make this to use even less lines without getting too overly complicated?   I'm finding that I have to do this bit of code on EVERY page that I use a form for two-way binding (is there a better approach?).

Any input would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there are many ways to do that.

I feel this is a simple way using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
  inputChangedHandler = (event) => {
    const id = [event.target.id];
    const value = [event.target.value];
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      form: {...prevState.form, 
           [id]: value
      }, isDirty: true
    }))
  }
```

Comment: I like this approach.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice guidance for using callback function with setState and prevent synthetic event pooling problem by caching event values.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make it shorter:

```
inputChangedHandler = (id, value) => {
    const { form } = this.state;

    this.setState({
       isDirty: true,
       form: Object.assign({}, form, { [id]: value }
       // or using lodash, this way you will be able to update nested object values
       form: Object.assign({}, form,  _.set(form, id, value)
    });
} 

...

<input id="username" onChange={({ target }) => inputChangeHandler(target.id, target.value)} />
```

though I would suggest you to use `reduxForm` https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/simple/